# Ruby, Append value to existing value for key value pair in hash table

Tags: ruby, json, hash, hashtable, multidimensional-array

I have a nested hash table.

If i write

```
 json.each{|key, value|
    puts value;
    puts;
    puts value[x];
    puts;
    puts value[x][0];
 }
```

I get a result along the lines of

Title1
name1
Title2
name2

Title1
name1

Title1

What I would like is be able to do something along the lines of

```
value[value.size][0] = Title3;
value[value.size][1] = name3;
```

so that this appends to the end of the values a new set however 
what i just did throws undefined method '[]=' so I was wondering
if anyone could help me to append values either this way or some other way
so that i can increase the amount of values associated to the same key whilst
maintaining the order in which they are associated with it. 
(Important for when I am logging the json values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `value[value.size]` evaluated to nil, `value[value.size][0] = Title3` evaluates to `nil[0] = Title3`, which is why you get the error you do. What you want to do instead is to append an array containing Title3 and name3 to value, so:

```
value[value.size] = [Title3, name3]
```

Or better use the method `push` instead of `value[value.size] =`:

```
value.push([Title3, name3])
```